# Cast sometimes throws exception, but "as" followed by dereference does not

Tags: c#

I hope this is appropriate for this site because I already figured out the answer, so it's more a quiz than a question.

This C# code works with no problem:

```
WidgetRef = widget as IWidget;
WidgetRef.Init();
```

However if I try changing it to:

```
WidgetRef = (IWidget)widget;
WidgetRef.Init();
```

in some situations I get a "cannot cast to IWidget" exception.

At first I was dumfounded how that could be possible, because if it can't cast in the 2nd example, it should throw a null exception in the 1st example.  But I discovered it ain't necessarily so :)

How is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there more to the C# "as" keyword than simple casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771629/is-there-more-to-the-c-as-keyword-than-simple-casting)

Comment: `Init()` being an extension method is one possibility.

Comment: I think that other question is not a dup. You'd need to provide more information on the Widget class and IWidget interface, such as how are they implemented? Keep in mind that the as keyword " The as operator cannot perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions."

Comment: I would agree with dlev, otherwise, the first example should fail also on .Init() with WidgetRef being null.

Comment: @dlev, that's not the case in my situation, and I really doubt that would work anyway... the compiler will always try to call IWidget.Init(), not an extension method

Comment: Funny how the question had 2 upvotes until I gave the answer, then it went down to 1.   I guess the question was better than the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the answer....

The incorrect assumption that I was making as that `WidgetRef` was a variable or field.  It was actually a property, defined like this:

```
    private IWidget _widgetRef;
    private IWidget WidgetRef
    {
        get { return _widgetRef ?? new NullWidget(); }
        set { _widgetRef = value; }
    }
```

where `NullWidget` is a class implementing `IWidget` in a minimal way.  So even though `null` was being assigned in to `WidgetRef`, that wasn't what was coming out of it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that there is something going on in the rest of your code that is making the widget object not "castable".  Cast and "As" are not quite the same thing.  Perhaps this article might give you some ideas.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: The article does not apply to my situation, where I'm casting to an *interface*

Answer (score 0):

They generate different IL so it's not the same thing entirely. I guess all depends on how you defined IWidget and WidgetRef. I couldn't tell you exactly what is causing the behaviour.

Maybe Init is a static method, so it can run in example 1 since 'as' doesn't throw exceptions.

Since you're saying 'in some situations' it throws an exception the problem is not with the .Init() but with the casting.

Answer (score -1):

The `as` operator will return null if it fails to perform the cast.

`as` operator on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The as keyword will behave the same as the casting keyword except that it will set the object to null rather than throw an exception when the cast fails.